# Python: Trying to open web pages in IDLE with Selenium = ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, geckodriver

I'm new to Python and following the Automate The Boring Stuff book (https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/)

Currently I am stuck with an error. I have been googling it for hours but cannot seem to come to find something similar or that works for me.

Here is what my code is:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('https://google.com')
```

and I keep getting met with this error:

```
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

In addition to installing selenium with pip.exe, I also had to install Geckodriver. I added Geckodriver to PATH to fix another error. I have also tried adding Python, IDLE, Geckodriver, and Selenium to windows firewall exceptions. Lastly, I have disabled all components of my antivirus (Avast).

Any recommendations or things I can try? My goal is to perform manipulations on webpages like clicking fields, entering text, etc.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Geckodriver was the issue. I was using 0.21. By downloading 0.20.1, and running the same commands as above, the error went away. I am still noticing some issues connecting to certain websites, but I have yet to get the 10053 error with multiple attempts.